# Custom c# installer class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to install some folders along with my app - folders with help files. How should I do that? Right now I've added two files to a setup projects as assemblies, though I don't know how to get to those files in the Install method of my installer class, and copy them to correct folders...
I even don't know if those files are being added to installer, so if someone would explain me how to install custom files along with my application - step by step, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a setup project to your project and mention what all items should be copied to the destination install directory when you install it. I did the same thing and written it here for anyone wish to do it.

http://www.techiesweb.net/2008/07/setting-path-while-installing-an-application-visual-studio-2005-setup-project/

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm afraid that your solution don't really apply to what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to embed file, say, smth.txt into installer, and then during installation process copy it into a folder c:\My_program_help\ Though I think, your post may be of use in the future, so anyway thanks :).